# mask and concatenate two string series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, mask

I am struggling to get this to work. I am masking out the NaN's then concatenating the two series. Is it not possible to concatenation using `+` in this way? If not what is the best way?

```
    row_mask = df[df[win_end].notnull()]
    df.loc[row_mask, df['window_full']] = df.loc[row_mask, win_start]+' - '+df.loc[row_mask, win_end]
    print(df['window_start', 'window_end', 'window_full'])
```

input

```
win_start     win_end
2021-12-16    2021-12-18
2022-01-19    NaN
2022-01-18    2022-01-20
```

expected output

```
win_start     win_end        window_full
2021-12-16    2021-12-18     2021-12-16 - 2021-12-18
2022-01-19    NaN            NaN
2022-01-18    2022-01-20     2022-01-18 - 2022-01-20
```

error

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for your quick reply. So I tried that using `'window_full'` but still getting an error:-

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

**EDIT 2**
working solution required bool mask to be passed:-

```
row_mask = df['win_end'].notnull()
df.loc[row_mask, 'window_full'] = (df.loc[row_mask, 'win_start']+' - '+df.loc[row_mask, 'win_end'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assign new column use column name instead Series `df['window_full']`, same like syntax like selecting, also is necessary pass boolean mask instead filtered DataFrame `row_mask = df[df[win_end].notnull()]`:

```
row_mask = df['win_end'].notnull()
df.loc[row_mask, 'window_full'] = (df.loc[row_mask, 'win_start']+' - '+
                                   df.loc[row_mask, 'win_end'])
```

Or test both columns:

```
row_mask = df[['win_end', win_start]].notnull().any(axis=1)
df.loc[row_mask, 'window_full'] = (df.loc[row_mask, 'win_start']+' - '+
                                   df.loc[row_mask, 'win_end'])
```